# How to share the last 19000 photos uploaded to Google Photos

Tags: google-photos, photo-sharing

So I just uploaded our family photo collection (a few more than 19,000 photos) to google photos, under my personal account, but now I'd like to share them with the rest of my family.

What I've tried so far:
I found a `recently uploaded` page on Google Photos. I selected the last 19,000 and clicked the share button, but it crashed chrome. (Tried again, with the same results.)  I'd still be open to this option, but I have a feeling I'm not going to get anywhere.

Is there another option?  Or a way where 19,000 photos won't crash my browser?  Would a more powerful computer or a different browser work better?  Thanks guys.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I'm using the free tier.

Comment: To get an answer if a more powerful computer will handle it - check you computer's and chrome's task managers, and see what they say and how they act.